# Stuck solving this indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

**Problem:** Solve integral:

[image]

**Approaches** I've tried:

1. Solving by parts led me nowhere but to more confusion (maybe I've taken the wrong parts?):
   [image]
2. Trying to replace $1+x$ or $1-x$ with another variable led me to the same integral but with different variable names.

I've found this interesting integral on one of the math forums, but I just can't wrap my head around the solution to it. I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: I suspect there there is no simple answer.

Comment: This smells Elliptical... And judging by the expression of the integrand, it will also be a pain.

Comment: Are you sure about this, anyway? If, to say, we had $x^2$ instead of $x^3$ inside the square root, then it would be easy and fast-solvable.

Comment: Exactly, this was my initial thought, but the OP said that there was $x^3$

Comment: @JoshJohnson Might be a textbook misprint, perhaps?

Comment: @JoshJohnson I can ensure you that that $x^3$ makes things "almost impossible". You said you found it on a forum, is there some hint, answer or else?

Comment: @EllipticCurve it might as well be a misprint. I'll keep the question open for a while though, maybe there is in fact some non-trivial solution. 

I will try to ask OP for some hints, but I can't guarantee that I'll be able to get an answer from him..

Comment: @JoshJohnson Don't worry, leave it open. No one ever knows... Anyway I checked for the results with W. Mathematica and as I said, it's a huge pain. That much that I am not even able to report it here.